# Gitlab ci rule for merge request event not works as expected

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline, pull-request, merge-request

I have a gitlab pipeline and I'm trying to set a rule for a merge request event, i want to fire the rule when i have a merge request and the source branch is different from main and develop. I do that in my job.

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^develop|^main/
```

If i just do that it works

```
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

The variable `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` is available.

But it seems that the regex doesn't works or the `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question the regex was wrong. To resolve my problem i do that
I just simply split the evalution in two steps

1. I check if the source is a merge request event and it is on branch develop or main. In that case i will not execute the pipeline.

otherwise i will go to the step 2 that will evaluate the merge request event, but for other branches different from main or develop

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^develop|^main/
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      changes:
        - 'yarn.lock'
```